# Custom events vs callbacks for jQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is better architectural solution for my own plugins to give ability to extend them -- callbacks (like many other plugins do) or custom events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO it is always better to use events in a plugin which is for the general public. But if you are looking for better performance and is a support plugin, rather than a standalone plugin, then it is always better to use [callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/) (as there is no event bubbling emulated).

It is better to use [jQuery.Callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/) (since v1.7) which is, as per the documentation:

> A multi-purpose callbacks list object that provides a powerful way to manage callback lists.

rather than a custom callbacks handler.

Comment: thanks for the link, it looks like a third option.

Comment: the `Callbacks` is not a different option, it is a implementation, of callbacks, that is used extensively in jquery (see [source-code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js)). and as @kernel-james says, `Deferred` doesn't quite qualify as callback list, rather as a subset of callbacks list, as it will fire only once (also see [source-code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js))

Answer (score 3):

They are pretty similar, but callbacks have one significant drawback: you can only attach one.

And with events your library consumers can bind as much handlers as they want.

So - personally I vote for events.

Comment: What about an array of callbacks being passed? It all depends on the requirements of the plugin...

Comment: @Lix: you need to have all of them in one place. While with events you can bind handlers in different parts of application. Indeed that it depends though, but as a general solution - events is more flexible

Comment: By "all in one place" I assume you mean when initializing the plugin you need to feed all of the callbacks in one array... This is not necessarily true... Implementing an `addCallback` function would allow you to add callbacks anywhere in the application as well. (unless I misunderstood your point...)

Comment: Why so many plugins (and even jQuery itself, for example for animation, ajax etc) provide callbacks? I understand that for any non-trivial app one can trigger custom events in these callbacks, but...

Comment: @Lix: yep, and `addCallback(name, callback)` becomes 100% equal to binding to events :-)

Comment: @artvolk: I think because for end-users callbacks are slightly easier to deal with

Comment: I guess you are right... so we are back to square one :P

Answer (score 1):

Use [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/Deferred.html) and [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)'s `Deferred` object for callbacks that allows for multiple callbacks. It is an implementation of the `Promise` design pattern.